# ReactJs - add attribute value for input

Tags: reactjs, attributes

I need add attribute VALUE for input depending on the state of the parameter isValue

```
{this.state.isValue ?
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value={this.state.amount} />
:
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" />
}
```

If I use this code - I have emtpy value in html code (if isValue = false)

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value={this.state.isValue ? this.state.amount : null} />
```

Is it possible to do this in a more elegant way? For example, I try like this, but it doesn't work...

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" {this.state.isValue ? value=this.state.amount : null} />
```

Comment: `If I use this code - I have emtpy value in html code (if isValue = false)`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @preciousbetine I would like to see the VALUE attribute only when isValue = true, and when isValue = false - not show the empty VALUE in the html code.

Comment: Well, that doesn't make any difference to the user. The difference is all in the code

Comment: @preciousbetine My inputs are displayed dynamically and this is important for the performance of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Too bad no one could help me.

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" {...(this.state.isValue ? {value: this.state.amount} : {})} />
```